# I want to make a list view with two columns in android.why is it not working

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, multiple-columns

This is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


//private static Button buttonPst;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                                          Intent I = new Intent();
                                                          I.setAction("android.amila.action.PST");
                                                          startActivity(I);

                                                      }
                                                  }
    );


}
```

}

Custom_row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rowTitle"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:typeface="normal" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rowSubtitle"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

and this is xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_pst"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"


tools:context="com.example.amila.newglossary.pst"
>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/pstList" />
```

.java file

```
public class pst extends Activity {

String[] englishName = new String[]{"bacon", "Ham", "Tuna", "Candy", "Meatball", "Potato"};
String[] sinhalaName = new String[]{"wdddbhha", "wdddbhha", "wdddbhha", "wdddbhha", "wa", "wa"};
// Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_pst);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pstList);
    adapter ada= new adapter(this,englishName,sinhalaName);



    listView.setAdapter(ada);
}
```

}

this is adapter class

```
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
String[] englishName;
String[] sinhalaName;
Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public adapter(Context context, String[] englishName,String[] sinhalaName) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row,englishName);
this.c=context;
    this.englishName=englishName;
    this.sinhalaName=sinhalaName;
}
public class ViewHolder{
TextView englishTv;
TextView sinhalaTv;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
    }
final ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();
    holder.englishTv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTitle);
    holder.sinhalaTv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowSubtitle);

    holder.englishTv.setText(englishName[position]);
    holder.sinhalaTv.setText(sinhalaName[position]);
    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
}
```

I have tried this very much and the first window(main activity) is running without errors when pressing the PST,the window with the list view not appears. this error appears in RUN and closes the app

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.amila.newglossary, PID: 6309
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.amila.newglossary/com.example.amila.newglossary.pst}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
>                         at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:419)
>                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
>                         at com.example.amila.newglossary.pst.onCreate(pst.java:42)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Adapter return the view you customized instead of returning super

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                   c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
        holder.englishTv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTitle);
        holder.sinhalaTv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowSubtitle);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.englishTv.setText(englishName[position]);
    holder.sinhalaTv.setText(sinhalaName[position]);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: it worked for me.can You suggest a way to apply a external font(another language) to 2nd column?.I am trying a glossary app.so that One column should be in another language.